# Wrong display when using QQuickWidget in Qt windows

Tags: qt, qml

I have tried to use QQuickWidget as background of my application.
I created 2 classes: KViewer (load QML file) and GUI (main GUI of application)

GUI.cpp

```
    GUI::GUI(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    {
    setFixedSize(500, 500);
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    KViewer* viewer = new KViewer(this);
    viewer->resize(size());
    QLabel* label = new QLabel("TEXT HERE");
    label->setFixedSize(400, 400);
    label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    label->setStyleSheet("QLabel {"
                         "background-color: yellow;"
                         "border-radius: 6px;"
                         "}");
    layout->addWidget(label);
    }
```

and KViewer.cpp

```
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    layout->setSpacing(0);
    layout->setMargin(0);
    QQuickWidget* mQQuickWidget = new QQuickWidget;
    mQQuickWidget->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
    mQQuickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/main.qml"));
    layout->addWidget(mQQuickWidget);
```

what I received

[Label corner with border-radius problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPIxn.png)

There's something wrong at corner of my label. Why black color here? Please help me solve this problem. Is there any other ways to use QML object as background of Qt application?

Answer (score 0):

I have already test some demo before, you maybe need to use Absolute positioning to layout your widgets in gui.cpp．

Comment: I think the position is not problem, because the position of QLabel and my QML object are all right. The problem is when I use QML Object, my QLabel with stylesheet (as in my code) appear black color (as in my [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zPIxn.png))